# Visual Studio 2010/2008 "Exception of type 'System.OutofMemoryEception' was thrown" error after clicking design form

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, crash, out-of-memory

My project include 350 forms, 780 thousand lines of code (350 thousand designer code).

But when i want to design form, every two or three design VS gives "Exception of type 'System.OutofMemoryEception' was thrown" error.

I am restart the project and this error gone until rebuild or open a few form... I couldn' work over 5 minutes...

I am looking at memory usage : devenv.exe using 500/600 mb and my sistem using 1.9 GB ram of 4GB ram 
I don't think so but is VS crash or not support 350 forms in project?

Is there any solution about VS memory options?

This is screenshot :
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/22517/

**My system spesifics is;**

```
Intel Core i5 CPU
4 GB RAM
Operation system :Windows XP 32 bit (at the windows 7 problem is same)
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (at Visual Studio 2008 Professional SP1 problem is the same)
```

**Call Stacks**

```
at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s)
at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.get_AssemblyName()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.get_Assembly()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.AssemblyEntry.Search(String fullName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly, String description)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchProjectEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Assembly& assembly, ReferenceType refType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ReferenceType refType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean reportError)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeAssignStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

Comment: have you profiled your program to see how much memory it consumes while running?

Comment: what can 350 forms do, that 10 can't?

Comment: Thanks for interests,
Chris, I have 32 bit OS. I edited my first post for this information.
I have already got another class library (for functions ,db connecitions etc) 
Anders, no 
But I have got a lot of memory in the system while VS is crashing...

Comment: And ChrisBD,e-MEEE, i avoid duplication form. For example only one  "description" form include 20 different description .. If it not, my form count over one thousand...

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether you're running 32 or 64 bit XP. I would hazard a guess that you're running 32 and have just reached the limits of your PC. You'll only get around 2 Gigs virtual memory on most systems.

Either way I would seriously consider looking at restructuring your project as 350 WinForms seems pretty excessive to me. There must be some be some way in which you can reduce this to avoid duplication or to create class library projects that you can offload some of the functionality into.

You could give [Solution Load Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66350dbe-ed01-4120-bea2-5564eff7b0b2/) a try to mark projects and files as load on demand rather than on start up.